# Make different color (or lighten the color) for dots from smoothing line with ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

With ggplot, I plot a figure like this

```
df = data.frame(xx= seq(1,100),yy=rnorm(100)*2,
                zz = rep(c("a","b"),50))

ggplot(aes(x = xx, y = yy, color = zz, group = zz), data = df) + geom_smooth() + geom_point() + theme_bw() 
  theme(legend.title=element_blank())
```

`

My original dataset has a lot of dots. Because of the same color between smoothing lines and dots in same groups, this type of figure with my data is so messy.

I would like to make pale color (or change color manually) for dots and show the lines more clearly.

How to have different colors for dots and lines with such figure?

Comment: Can you share your data, code & plot? [How to make a great R reproducible example?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)

Comment: Thank you. I forgot to add a dataframe. I just edited it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm understanding what you want correctly, you have a couple options to make the points stand out:

- If the standard error shading on the lines is in your way, add `se = F` to `geom_smooth()`
- Decrease the opacity of the points: `geom_point(alpha = 0.5)`
- Change the shape of the points, for example to unfilled circles: `geom_point(shape = 1)`
- Make the points smaller: `geom_point(size = 0.5)`

It's up to you which of those routes (or combination of them) you choose, but you can decide which you think is most readable for your purposes.